# Strange Android Customer Error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

My app had been chugging along fine on the Android market until last night when it was reported a customer found an error. The customer must have downloaded the latest version of the app because he tried to use it again with the latest version and the error came back.

I looked at the stack trace of the error and found it was caused by a NullPointerException when passing information between two activities, namely with the onActivityResult() method.

I checked the code and can't find what could have caused the error. I tried to figure out what steps the user took to get the error, but found nothing wrong, on the emulator Android 1.6 /Android 2.2 and my own phone (Android 2.2). I couldn't find any problems no matte rhow much I tried to crash the system.

Another thing that is strange is that the particular onActivityResult method is called a lot in my app. So it is odd that only one user has reported problems.

Also, it says the user's platform is "OTHER". I don't know what device that could be.

So my questions are:
1) Could this problem be an issue with the user's device and not my application?
2)What to do when you cannot find the cause of a crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, they may have a custom ROM; they're known for doing things like this.

2) Unless you can reproduce it, you [probably] can't fix it.

Can you contact this customer? If not, there may be nothing you can do.

Comment: Well the customer sent a message asking for a refund. No other info was given, so I dont know which customer it is. And technically it is outside the 15min window of opportunity for refunds, although if it was some serious error in my app I would refund, if I could.

Comment: I don't know how much a refund would be.. but it may be worth it to get more details about the user environment where it bugged out.. You may need to disclaim custom ROM's and rooted devices and such

Comment: How did they send the message? Do you have an e-mail for them, or did they just leave a comment? If that's the case, your only real option is to add some text to the apps description asking anyone with a problem to send a support e-mail and hope you can find a way to get ahold of them. Unfortunately, it sounds like you're caught in a communication trap honest developers hate.

Comment: The user left a comment associated with the error. I'm beginning to suspect it could be due to a custom ROM

Comment: I'm the type that likes to tinker with my Android devices as such. I hosed my contacts/dialer a week or so ago when I did. I fully accept that by [rooting, freezing system apps, loading custom ROMs/Kernels, etc], I may break things, and I have to deal with it. Some people don't feel that way though. That's the down-side of an "open" platform.

Comment: Keep in mind, they may also be using one of those cheap ePad/APad type devices; in which case, there's no telling what's been done to the OS (and they believe because it came pre-installed, they can trust it).